# Default account is not reflected in Web3 instance created from injected current provider

Tags: web3js, metamask

According to the [MetaMask docs](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check) the recommended way to access the `web3` is by creating a new instance of the `Web3` class by passing the `window.web3.currentProvider`, which is injected by the MetaMask extension, to it's constructor:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
```

However, when instantiated this way, the `web3.eth.defaultAccount` property is `null` and when I change accounts in the extension, the current account is not reflected in the `Web3` instance.

On contrary, when I use the `Web3` instance, which is injected directly, it works perfectly fine. I can access the `web3.eth.defaultAccount` right away and it's updated dynamically when I change current account in the extension:

```
const web3 = window.web3;
```

Why is that and how do I implement the correct integration with MetaMask?

---

- MetaMask version: 3.12.1
- web3 version: 0.19.0

Answer (score 0):

Try `web3.eth.accounts[0]`.

Or async, `web3.eth.getAccounts(_accounts => selectedAccount = _accounts[0])`.
This will save the currently selected Metamask account to `selectedAccount`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to get an instance of web3.

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const getWeb3 = async () => {
  let web3Instance;
  let accounts;

  if (window.ethereum) {
    web3Instance = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    try {
      accounts= await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });
      console.log("accounts: ", accounts);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("User denied account access");
      throw new Error("User denied account access");
    }
  } else if (window.web3) {
    web3Instance = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.error("No web3 instance found, please install MetaMask");
    throw new Error("No web3 instance found, please install MetaMask");
  }

  return { web3Instance, accounts };
};

export default getWeb3;
```

After that you can use:

```
const {web3Instance} = await getWeb3();
const accounts = await web3Instance.eth.getAccounts();
```

to get the account.
or, use the following to get the account:

```
const {account} = await getWeb3();
```